# How to avoid duplicate identical entity creation with accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making up this example for the sake of demonstrating my issue. Let's say we have the following models:

```
class Case < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :clients
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :clients
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :case
    has_many :attorneys
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :attorneys
end

class Attorney < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client
end
```

I'd like to add the ***same*** ***new*** attorney to different clients.

If I use params like this to update a case:

```
{
  "clients_attributes"=>{
    "0"=>{
      "id"=>"1",
      "attorneys_attributes"=>{
        "123"=>{
          "name"=>"Joe"
        }
      }
    },
    "1"=>{
      "id"=>"2",
      "attorneys_attributes"=>{
        "456"=>{
          "name"=>"Joe"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Rails will create two new attorney records with the same name "Joe". I'd like to just create one record and have both clients refer to it. Is there some clever was to reference an *as yet uncreated* record?

One thing I could do is check the params on the server side for identical names and do some post-update work. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Have you though about using a dropdown selection for users to choose pre existing attorneys from?

Comment: @DollarChills remember, the example above is made up to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rails check if it's same record via the ID. Therefore, if you're using nested fields, but want to reuse the attorney record, then you need to make sure their ID are the same.

On the other hand, why do you want to use nested field? Usually you have a nested form to update the information, but for your case here.. that would means to update the attorney information under any of the client model - and updating attorney under one client, would actually affect all the same attorney under other clients.

As @DollarChills put in the comments, why not use a select field for the attorney under client, and create a separate page to update the attorney information?

Update: auto-complete solution

1. For the fields you feel can uniquely identify the an attorney, create a auto-complete field, based on that field. Let's take `name` for example
2. If the user put in the name match some DB record, load it and let the user select. You'll also have a `create new attorney` option
3. If user selected the attorney, just load it into the form with corresponding ID, so that your app knows who to update.

Comment: The example is made up to demonstrate the issue. I cannot "make sure their ID are the same" since the ID for the newly created attorney doesn't exist when the params are being constructed.

Comment: @KeithCarter what's ur actual use case? For a given client, you want to reuse attorneys if it already exist, is it?

Comment: In that case, you can make the name field auto-complete. Once a existing attorneys are selected, then auto fill-in the nested fields with existing attorney loaded from the auto-complete

Comment: the use case is I'd like to add one entity to the database in the case where there are two entities in the params hash with the identical name.

Comment: Sounds to me the `autocomplete` solution would resolve your use case :)

Comment: I appreciate the effort here, but I think you are misunderstanding the question. Specifically, I am not selecting existing attorneys, I'm adding new ones.

Comment: adding new ones, and re-use on duplicated attorney, right?